# SaltStack - Copy war file into JBoss 5.1 using SALT

Tags: jboss, saltstack

Hi ServerFault community,

I have a war file that I want to deploy in JBoss 5.1 via Salt. 'archive.extracted' module seems to not work. I've read in salt docs about 'jboss7.deployed' module but I think it will work only on JBoss 7? Upgrading from 5.1 to 7 is not an option. Can someone help me or can give me ideas? Appreciate your help guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

archive.extracted should work. What version of salt are you running? Are you receiving and error when you try to use that module or state?

But if all you want to do is copy a single war file from the master the the minion you can just use the file.managed state.

Comment: Hi @Ch3LL, salt version is 2015.8.3.. Don't know, there's no error in the logs. However, file.managed seems to work. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: no problem. glad it worked :)